# Minimize the expected cost of visiting all leaves of a tree

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a given rooted tree where I need to reach all leaves atleast once (and stop at the last leaf I visit in the entire tour). We need to minimize the expected cost of visiting all leaves. Every hop of an edge costs 1 unit.

My approach : For each node, I calculate 3 parameters : expected value to visit all leaves in the subtree of that node, the number leaves (directly or indirectly attached to the node) in the subtree and overhead which is the number of hops to visit all leaves and then come back to the node. Assuming I know the optimal path to visit the subtrees, I now need to combine them somehow to minimize the cost of the whole tree. A brute force combination check is very large, so I was thinking there might be other efficient ways to do this.

Comment: In practice if the tree is large it will be faster to visit nodes which are closer to each other in memory because of cache issues. Other than that I don't think the order should matter, as long as you do some "depth first" scan.

Comment: The traversal starts from the root and can stop at *any* leaf, right? So, for each particular leaf you need to find a *minimum-cost* traversal and then to average all costs? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @HEKTO The traversal stops at a leaf only if we have visited all other leaves.

Comment: I think your traversal is somehow different from the classical tree traversal - please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal. You said "reach all leaves at least once" - did you mean "exactly once"? Your cost function is also unclear. For example, the BFS traverses nodes on the same level, but there are no edges between them - it's possible because the algorithm stores some nodes in the stack. Do you allow usage of any data structures? What will be your minimal cost to traverse a rooted tree with two leaves - 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to traverse all leaves in a rooted tree with $E$ edges starting from the root *and ending in this root* then it will cost you $2 \cdot E$ (it doesn't depend on the traversal you choose, right?). If you stop at some leaf $n$ because you've already visited all other leaves then it'll cost you $2 \cdot E - depth(n)$. So, to minimize the cost you need to choose your traversal to stop at the leaf $n$ with **maximal** $depth(n)$.

I hope I understood your question correctly... besides the *expected* cost you asked about.

Comment: I dont think I explained my question precisely but I get the gist of your answer and got the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the order you visit the subtrees does not matter, so you can avoid the combinatorial explosion.  As an example, suppose the root has six branches, each the root of a subtree.  Your optimal path will start at the far end of one subtree, come down to the root, cover four more subtrees returning to the root, and finally cover the last subtree without returning.  The order you do the middle four subtrees does not matter.

Also note that the number of moves to cover a subtree when not returning to the root is the same as the number to start at the top of the subtree and end at the root, so for each subtree you need the number of moves to cover it root-to-root and the number of moves to cover it root-to-end.  When combining subtrees, the root-to-root sum is just the sum of the subtrees plus twice the number of upward edges from the root.  For the root-to-end path you find the subtree with the greatest difference between root-to-end and root-to-root and use that as your root-to-end.